# Microsoft Applocker - GUI vs PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, applocker

[image]

Dear community,

1 and 2 - While using AppLocker GUI - why is the application NOT able to detect the Publisher Name? It resorts to File Hash Rule being created as a result.

3 and 4 - when I use the PowerShell CMDLet, it's able to detect the Publisher Name?

---- Second Snip ----
[image]

.. I'd really appreciate a Blog wherein I could understand what is this Publisher name? I checked and both EXEs have the same cert even. Why this disparity?
Any AppLocker/PS Whiz - please help!